# index out of bounds// Python, dataframe, plot

Tags: python, plot

I want to plot the point with max value from dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dane = pd.read_table('C:\\xxx.txt', names=('rok', 'kroliki', 'lisy', 'marchewki'))
df = pd.DataFrame(dane)

data = df[1:]
data=data.astype(float)

x = int(data['kroliki'].max())
y = int(data['lisy'].max())
z = int(data['marchewki'].max())

p= data['rok'].where(data['kroliki'] == x)
q = data['rok'].where(data['lisy'] == y)
r = data['rok'].where(data['marchewki'] == z)

p1 = int(p[p.notnull()])
q1 = int(q[q.notnull()])
r1 = int(r[r.notnull()])
point = pd.DataFrame({'x':[p1],'y':[q1],'z':[r1]})
point.plot((p1,x),(q1,y),(r1,z))
```

I have such an error:

```
IndexError: index 1993 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
```

May somebody know what is wrong with this code?
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? Can you also provide some example data so the above code will reproduce the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you use Pandas to plot, it will look for indices within itself and not for values.

So, in your case, when you do:

```
point.plot(p1,x)
```

Pandas will look for the index **1993** in the x-direction, i.e, throughout all columns. In other words, you should have 1993 columns.

I tried to reproduce your problem as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=('rok', 'kroliki', 'lisy', 'marchewki'))

data = df[1:]
data=data.astype(float)

x = int(data['kroliki'].max())
y = int(data['lisy'].max())
z = int(data['marchewki'].max())

p = data['rok'].where(data['kroliki'] == x)
q = data['rok'].where(data['lisy'] == y)
r = data['rok'].where(data['marchewki'] == z)

p1 = int(p[p.notnull()])
q1 = int(q[q.notnull()])
r1 = int(r[r.notnull()])

point = pd.DataFrame({'x':[p1],'y':[q1],'z':[r1]})
point.plot((p1,x),(q1,y),(r1,z))
```

I get the following error:

```
>>> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

And when I run each point separately:

```
>>>> IndexError: index 85 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

To solve it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot((point.x, point.y, point.z), (x,y,z),'ko')
```

And I got the following result:

[image]

Hope it helps.